# Como pegar um tipo de dado específico de um arquivo texto

Tags: python

Tenho um arquivo texto, estruturado da seguinte maneira

- 1
- Nome
- CPF
- Endereço
- Telefone

gostaria de saber como eu faço para pegar somente as linhas que contem inteiro, no caso o código(identificado como 1), pois estou tentando fazer um auto incremento em python
Obs: há alguma coisa que eu deva fazer para melhorar essa formatação, agradeço os comentários

Obs: Código de escrita

```
codigo = verifica_codigo_cliente()
nome = raw_input("Digite o nome do Cliente: ")
cpf = raw_input("Digite o CPF do Cliente: ")
endereco = raw_input("Digite o endereço do Cliente: ")
telefone = raw_input("Digite o telefone do Cliente: ")
arquivo_cliente.write(codigo)
arquivo_cliente.write("\n" + nome + "\n")
arquivo_cliente.write(cpf + "\n")
arquivo_cliente.write(endereco + "\n")
arquivo_cliente.write(telefone + "\n\n")
```

Função para verificar o codigo, foi onde me perdi

```
def verifica_codigo_cliente():
arquivo_cliente = open("arquivo_cliente.txt", "a+")
codigos = []
for row in arquivo_cliente:
    codigos.append(row)
if codigos == []:
    return 1
else:
    x = codigos[len]
    return codigos[x]
```

Comment: Você já sabe como fazer para abrir e ler um arquivo em Python?

Comment: Sim, consigo abrir o arquivo e até ler os dados dele. o problema é que não entendi bem a diferença entre read, readline e readlines, mesmo após ler a documentação

Comment: Pode colocar esse código na pergunta?

Comment: já o coloquei na pergunta

Comment: Antes de responder, você já cogitou algum formato melhor para armazenar os dados, tal como CSV?

Comment: o arquivo deve ser em txt, mas se eu estrutura-lo com vírgula depois de cada dado, ainda vai funcionar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Corrigindo a função `verifica_codigo_cliente()`

```
# Identação errada
def verifica_codigo_cliente():
# "a+" = read e append.A função só faz leitura,substitua por 'r'
arquivo_cliente = open("arquivo_cliente.txt", "a+")
codigos = []
#Podemos ler apenas a última linha ao invés de iterar todo o arquivo
for row in arquivo_cliente:
    codigos.append(row)
if codigos == []:
    return 1
else:
    #uso correto: x = len(codigos)
    x = codigos[len]
    return codigos[x]
```

#### Função reescrita:

```
def verifica_codigo_cliente(arquivo):
    try:
        arquivo_clientes = open(arquivo, 'r')
        ultima_linha = arquivo_clientes.readlines()[-1]
        #separa primeira coluna da ultima linha(separador=",")
        id = ultima_linha.split(",")[0]
        return id
    except:
        return 1
    finally:
        arquivo_clientes.close()
```

## Programa reescrito

> há alguma coisa que eu deva fazer para melhorar essa formatação, agradeço os comentários

Reescreví seu código usando o módulo `csv`(que o [Anderson](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/anderson-carlos-woss) mencionou).O formato é o mesmo que vc queria usar,pelo que deu a entender:

- cada dado é separado por vírgula
- um cliente em cada linha
- inicia-se com um "id",que vai incrementando conforme mais clientes são
  adicionados

> arquivo deve ser em txt, mas se eu estrutura-lo com vírgula depois de cada dado, ainda vai funcionar?

CSV é texto puro,é só salvar em `.txt` ao invés de `.csv`.Qualquer dúvida é só perguntar!

OBS: escrito para python3

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import csv
import os

arquivo = "clientes.txt"

def arquivo_existe():
    return os.path.isfile(arquivo)

def proximo_id():
    with open(arquivo, 'r') as arquivo_clientes:
        reader = csv.reader(arquivo_clientes)
        ultima_linha = list(reader)[-1]
        id = ultima_linha[0]
        return (int(id)+1)

def escreve_dados(id, nome, cpf, endereco, telefone):
    with open(arquivo, 'a') as arquivo_clientes:
        writer = csv.writer(arquivo_clientes)
        writer.writerow([id, nome, cpf, endereco, telefone])

nome = input("Digite o nome do cliente: ")
cpf = input("Digite o CPF do cliente:   ")
endereco = input("Digite o endereco do cliente: ")
telefone = input("Digite o Telefone do cliente: ")
if(arquivo_existe()):
    escreve_dados(str(proximo_id()), nome, cpf, endereco, telefone)
else:
    escreve_dados(1, nome ,cpf, endereco, telefone)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas dicas, ajudou bastante

Comment: De nada,João!Agradeço se puder aceitar minha resposta como a correta